# Is it advisable to install Ubuntu on btrfs or ext4?

Tags: system-installation, ext4, btrfs

I used to install ubuntu on ext4 but I heard about btrfs. Is it advisable to use it for Ubuntu installation? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: ext4 is default for a reason. Unless you think you know more then the ubuntu developers or you know about btrfs, go with the defaults. The fact you have to ask answers your own question.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is a pure personal decision.

Basically btfrs is a filesystem where features ("Copy on Write" almost instant snapshots, subvolumes, [and many many more](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)) are more important than performance. 1 of the badass features is the snapshots: want to upgrade? Make a snapshot and if the upgrade kills you machine you are up and running on the old version within seconds.

So if you want a filesystem you can tinker with, do not care about performance (yet) and do not mind having to use the command line feel free to use btfrs.